# How to add image attachment to textarea

Tags: html, node.js, express

Hi i'm making a personal blog based on node js. When I write there, I want to attach an image and write a description, but I don't know what to do.
How to put image attachment function in textarea to write body content in textarea tag? I am curious what method to use.

Answer (score 0):

here is a code to add an image in the textarea.

I hope I have answered your question

Comment: " <textarea style="background-image: url(pic_trulli.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;"> 
</textarea> "